# Airflow xcom pull only returns string

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-sql

I have an airflow pipeline where I need to get a filename from a pubsub subscription and then import that file into a cloud sql instance. I use the CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator to import the CSV file. This operator needs a body, which contains the filename and other parameters. Since I read that filename during runtime, I also have to define the body during runtime. This all works. But when I pull the body from xcom, it returns a string instead of a python dictionary. So the CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator gives me the following error (my guess is, because the body is a string and not a dictionary):

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator.py", line 715, in execut
    self._validate_body_fields(
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator.py", line 712, in _validate_body_field
    api_version=self.api_version).validate(self.body
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/utils/gcp_field_validator.py", line 420, in validat
    dictionary_to_validate=body_to_validate
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/utils/gcp_field_validator.py", line 341, in _validate_fiel
    value = dictionary_to_validate.get(field_name
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get
```

This is the code I use:

```
import json 
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ast
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.pubsub_sensor import PubSubPullSensor
from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator import CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator


def create_dag(dag_id,default_args):
    BUCKET = "{{ var.value.gp2pg_bucket }}"
    GCP_PROJECT_ID = "{{ var.value.gp2pg_project_id }}"
    INSTANCE_NAME = "{{ var.value.gp2pg_instance_name }}"

    def define_import_body(file,**kwargs):
        import_body = {
            "importContext": {
                "importUser": "databasename",
                "database": "databaseuser",
                "fileType": "csv",
                "uri": "bucketname" + file,
                "csvImportOptions": {
                    "table": "schema.tablename",
                    "columns": ["columns1",
                                "column2"]}
            }
        }
        task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
        task_instance.xcom_push(key='import_body', value=import_body)
        print(import_body)

    def get_filename(var,**kwargs):
        message = ast.literal_eval(var)
        file = message[0].get('message').get('attributes').get('objectId')
        task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
        task_instance.xcom_push(key='filename', value=file)
        print(file)

    dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_id, schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PubSubPullSensor(task_id='pull-messages',
                              project="projectname",
                              ack_messages=True,
                              max_messages=1,
                              subscription="subscribtionname")


        message = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull() }}"

        t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='get_filename',
            python_callable=get_filename,
            op_kwargs={'var': message},
            provide_context=True,
        )

        file = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_filename', key='filename') }}"

        t3 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='define_import_body',
            python_callable=define_import_body,
            op_kwargs={'file': file},
            provide_context=True,
        )

        import_body = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_import_body', key='import_body') }}"

        t4 = CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator(
            project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
            body= import_body,
            instance=INSTANCE_NAME,
            gcp_conn_id='postgres_default',
            task_id='sql_import_task',
            validate_body=True,
        )

        t5 = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id='copy_files',
            source_bucket=BUCKET,
            source_object=file,
            destination_bucket=BUCKET,
            destination_object='processed/import/'+file, )

        t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5

    return dag


dags_folder = os.getenv('DAGS_FOLDER', "./dags")
flow_config = open(f'{dags_folder}/gp2pg/flow_config.json', 'r').read()
for key, values in json.loads(flow_config).items():
    default_args = {
        "owner": "owner",
        "start_date": datetime(2020, 1, 1),
        "email": [],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

    dag_id = f"gp2pg_{key}_data_to_pg"

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, default_args)
```

Any idea how I could solve that problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:**

For Airflow >= 2.1.0:
Airflow added the ability to render fields as native Python objects.
You need to set `render_template_as_native_obj=True` in your DAG constructor. You can follow this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects) example.

**Original Answer:**

First `CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator` is [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4e8f9cc8d02b29c325b8a5a76b4837671bdf5f68/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator.py#L119). You should use [CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/41bf172c1dc75099f4f9d8b3f3350b4b1f523ef9/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/cloud_sql.py#L919) from [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/)

The `body` param needs to be dict as explained in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export#request-body).

XCOM is a table in the database. The data is saved as strings.
You can't store dict in database as dict is a Python in memory object.
You probably have a Json (string). Try convert it to dict:

```
body=json.loads(import_body)
```

**EDIT:** (after discussion in comments)

You will need to wrap your operator with PythonOperator so you can convert the `xcom` to dict and use it.

```
def my_func(ds, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    body = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='privious_task_id')
    import_body = json.loads(body)
    op = CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator(
            project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
            body=import_body,
            instance=INSTANCE_NAME,
            gcp_conn_id='postgres_default',
            task_id='sql_import_task',
            validate_body=True,
        )
    op.execute()
    

p = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=my_func)
```

Noting that calling operator inside operator is not the best practice (reason is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71998563/14624409)) you can avoid it all together for Airflow>=2.1 as explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: Hmm I have the newest version of apache-airflow in my python environment but cannot find the providers folder in it..

body = json.loads(import_body) does not work. Now the whole pipeline fails. I also would have to cast the import_body in the CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator since it has to be cast during runtime.

Comment: providers is from Airflow 2.0 to use it you will need to install it like any python package. see the link I added to https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/

Comment: ah my bad, did not see the link to the providers pip page.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since the xcom value will be pulled during runtime, I cannot cast the value directly in the code, I would have to cast it in the operator. And when I try that, the whole pipelines fails with an error.

Comment: what error? You can change the pipe as follows: add PythonOperator. In the python callable pull the xcom. convert it to dict and then setup  `op = CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator` and call `op.execute()` .Basically wrap the CloudSql actions with PythonOperator.

Comment: render_template_as_native_obj is a very cool looking feature, unfortunately and as too often with Airflow, this doesn't work (airflow 2.4.3). Fields are still rendered as string, not python objects even though render_template_as_native_obj is set to True.

Comment: @Tchopane not sure whar you mean by that. Works fine for me and many others. If you have an issue I suggest open a question and ask about your specific case.

Answer (score 4):

As of Airflow 2.1 (to be released soon), you can pass `render_template_as_native_obj=True` to the dag and Airflow will return the Python type (dict, int, etc) instead of string. No other code changes are needed. See this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/14603)

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_template_as_python_object",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
```