# Return a python object from GKEPodOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG executing calling a GKEPodOperator where a python script is ran to process and load data to BigQuery. Can the GKEPodOperator return like a python list or dictionary from the executed script back to the DAG so I can make use of that to write custom emails using DAGOperator?

Answer (score 1):

First `GKEPodOperator` is deprecated. You should use `GKEStartPodOperator`.

Like other operators you can pass values between tasks with Xcom. Note that the `GKEStartPodOperator` inherits from `KubernetesPodOperator` thus the xcom mechanism is different than other operators. It works with launching a sidecar container. You can read more about it with examples [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/kubernetes_engine.html#use-of-xcom).

Now that you have the desired value stored as XCOM (as string) you want to pull it so you can use it in your custom operator:

1. `Airflow >= 2.1.0` (not yet released)
   There is native support for to convert xcom directly into native python object. See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/14603). You will need to set `render_template_as_native_obj=True`. You can read more about it in the docs: [Rendering Fields as Native Python Objects](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/concepts/operators.html)
2. `Airflow < 2.1.0`:
   In the follow up task you need to pull the xcom value and convert it to whatever Python object you'd like. You can see example for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895949/14624409).