# How do I pass jinja template to execution_timeout argument in Airflow DataBricksSubmitRunOperator?

Tags: airflow, databricks, azure-databricks

Usually the jinja template is passed inside double quotes to any operator in Airflow as shown below code,

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 16)
}

with DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    
    task1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        databricks_conn_id='databricks_default',
        existing_cluster_id="xyz-cluster-id",
        run_name='My Run',
        wait_for_completion=True,
        execution_timeout="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task_id', key='my_timeout') }}"
    )

    task2 = ...

    task1 >> task2
```

But as execution_timeout requires timedelta above code throwing error
`ValueError: execution_timeout must be timedelta object but passed as type <class 'str'>`

So I feel it should be passed as below,

```
task1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        databricks_conn_id='databricks_default',
        existing_cluster_id="xyz-cluster-id",
        run_name='My Run',
        wait_for_completion=True,
        execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task_id', key='my_timeout') }}")
    )
```

But now it's giving error as unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: str

I know that exection_timeout is not templated field so I have already creating a wrapper over DataBricksSubmitRunOperator to allow templating for exection_timeout field

**Note:** Above code is for reference purpose only, the execution_timeout would applicable for any custom operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format jinja template as INT in operator parameter in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235496/format-jinja-template-as-int-in-operator-parameter-in-airflow)

Comment: Nope, I am aware of this thing

Comment: And `render_template_as_native_obj=True` on DAG plus `execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task_id', key='my_timeout') | int }}")` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jinja templates as arguments [can only be done when the field is designated as a template field for a given operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/operators.html#jinja-templating). Unfortunately, parameters that are needed for the Scheduler (effectively parameters originating directly from the BaseOperator) are not templateable. Meaning, templating `execution_timeout` will not be possible in Airflow.

Below is a list of parameters that will not be able to be templateable in Airflow.

```py
'start_date'
'doc'
'executor_config'
'pre_execute'
'email'
'retry_exponential_backoff'
'depends_on_past'
'inlets'
'wait_for_downstream'
'email_on_failure'
'outlets'
'doc_json'
'execution_timeout'
'task_id'
'sla'
'on_success_callback'
'trigger_rule'
'ignore_first_depends_on_past'
'doc_md'
'pool'
'doc_rst'
'on_failure_callback'
'email_on_retry'
'weight_rule'
'priority_weight'
'pool_slots'
'run_as_user'
'task_group'
'doc_yaml'
'on_retry_callback'
'do_xcom_push'
'max_retry_delay'
'retries'
'owner'
'params'
'default_args'
'queue'
'resources'
'task_concurrency'
'max_active_tis_per_dag'
'wait_for_past_depends_before_skipping'
'retry_delay'
'on_execute_callback'
'dag'
'end_date'
'post_execute'
```

Comment: Better if we can document it somewhere.